# Can't get owner as foreign key to my model -- django

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a form so a user can upload a video, the problem is i can't get current user or it's id as a foreign key on my video model

Error: IntegrityError
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'owner_id' cannot be null")

How can i solve the problem please, i looked at django documentation but doesn't find answer.

My models.py:

```
class Videowtm(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
      uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
      video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
```

My forms.py:

```
class VideowtmForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Videowtm
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'video', )
```

My views:

```
@login_required
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = VideowtmForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       form.owner = request.user
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('home')
    else:
       form = VideowtmForm()
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {
    'form': form
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

first add `blank=True` to the owner in your model:

**###No need for this if you don't include it in your form fields###**

```
class Videowtm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
```

and then:

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = VideowtmForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          video = form.save(commit=False)
          video.owner = request.user
          video.save()
          return redirect('home')
    else:
       form = VideowtmForm()
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {
    'form': form
    })
```

Comment: I modified as you said and had the same

Comment: I don't have my laptop here to test it but i think by making an instance of the form might work. i edited the code (form.save(commit=False) to video = form.save(commit=False)). test this one and if it didn't work i'll check it my self to see whats wrong. good luck.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue

Comment: You don't need to set `blank=True`, because the `owner` field is not included in the form. The key part is to save with `commit=False`, set the `owner` then save it.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are correct. i didn't notice that it's not included in the form. Edited, thanks.